Table formatted incorrectly, partly missing border
Anybody have any ideas how I can fix this table: -
\begin{tabular}{ | p{4cm} | p{1.5cm}| p{1.5cm} | p{1.5cm} |l|} 
\hline
Dataset and Section  & MRR@1 & MRR@5 & MRR@10\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\emph{Data 1}} &  \\
Head & \textbf{0.72}  & 0.75 & 0.78 \\
Middle  & 0.43 & 0.44 & 0.48 \\
Tail      & 0.23 & 0.25 & 0.29\\
%& \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\emph{Data 2}} & \\
Head & \textbf{0.72}  & 0.75 & 0.78 \\
Middle  & 0.43 & 0.44 & 0.48 \\
Tail      & 0.23 & 0.25 & 0.29\\
%& \\ 

\hline
\end{tabular} \\



Unrelated and a matter of taste, but are you sure that a centred Data 1 below a left aligned header looks good?

Your row \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\emph{Data 2}} & \\  only has two cells, you need 4:
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{ | p{4cm} | p{1.5cm}| p{1.5cm} | p{1.5cm} |l|} 
\hline
Dataset and Section  & MRR@1 & MRR@5 & MRR@10\\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\emph{Data 1}} &&&  \\
Head & \textbf{0.72}  & 0.75 & 0.78 \\
Middle  & 0.43 & 0.44 & 0.48 \\
Tail      & 0.23 & 0.25 & 0.29\\
%& \\ 
\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\emph{Data 2}} &&& \\
Head & \textbf{0.72}  & 0.75 & 0.78 \\
Middle  & 0.43 & 0.44 & 0.48 \\
Tail      & 0.23 & 0.25 & 0.29\\
%& \\ 

\hline
\end{tabular} \\


\end{document}



Perfect - thank you Sam Carter

@Colin You're welcome!
